# Not able to display images from local directory like F: OR from application webapp folder in Spring web Application?

Tags: java, spring

I am creating one Spring Web App , In which I have uploaded images in local directory. But while displaying on jsp , its not able to display image from local dir or webapp/profile_pics folder. I have tried both the options ?

My Jsp Code :

```
      <img src="F:/image.jpg"/>
      <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/profile_pics/${profilePicName}"/>
```

Comment: What is the url of the image that is being generated on the page?

Comment: @Jeff Storey : The file is in Local Directory , this path is stored in database. Everything is fine. Image is there in that location , when I looking at the view source of the jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

Local file images cannot be accessed from a web server for security reasons. Imagine if a web page on another server had a reference to C:\myfile and they ran it on your machine.

The image should be somewhere that is accessible by your web server. Try putting it in your webapps directory, and then your jsp should be able to access it using a URL (either relative or absolute).

If the html page is being loaded from a file (and not on a server), the `<img>` take takes a URL, it should be `file://F:/image.jpg` See https://superuser.com/questions/352133/what-is-the-reason-that-file-urls-start-with-three-slashes-file-etc for the URL format. I suspect this is not the case though since you mentioned it was a jsp.

Comment: Oh, if it's a jsp page that is running on a server and the file is local, it can't access it (security reasons). This will only work if the page is also running from the local machine.

Comment: I tried one more option. I saved images in application's  webapp/profile_pics folder and that's also not working.Some people are saying it's refreshing problem. I have spent 2 days to display image on jsp page, but no success yet..

Comment: Once it's in the webapp/profile_pics folder, how are you trying to access it? When it's on the web server, you need to access it with a URL, so it probably be something like `/profile_pics/myimg.jpg` or `profile_pics/myimage.jpg` depending on if you want a relative reference.

Comment: It's like on jsp page :                                                 **<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/profile_pics/${profilePicName}"/>**

Comment: And what does the generated URL look like when the page is generated? Verify that the uRL is valid.

Comment: And while doing View source of jsp page , Its coming like this :              **<img src="/mcb/profile_pics/1358660082083_Sunlight.jpg"/>**

Comment: Is `http://yourserver//mcb/profile_pics/1358660082083_Sunlight.jpg` a valid URL? If it is, it should work. Try pasting it into the browser and seeing what you get.